# Should I use Thread.Sleep between a socket reception and another?

Tags: c#, sockets, thread-sleep

I have a loop in which I have to receive `N` bytes of data using a socket

```
int bytesRead = 0;
int offset = 0;

do
{
    var buffer = new byte[N - offset];
    bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, packet.Buffer, offset, bytesRead);
    offset += bytesRead;

    // Thread.Sleep(How much have I to sleep?);
}
while (offset < N);
```

`packet.Buffer` is where I store all data.

Should I use `Thread.Sleep` between a socket reception and another to wait that enough data has arrived? If yes, how many milliseconds?

Comment: Note that the data will also be buffered at lower levels of abstraction, so that will likely prevent you from getting overly small amounts of data at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to sleep - the `socket.Receive` call will block until data is available.

From the [relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5.aspx)

> ...If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block
>   until data is available...

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. It is literally a waste of time. The receive will block until data or EOS arrives, and it will block for exactly the correct length of time. Adding a sleep is pointless.